# Java SAXException: No deserializer for

Tags: java, json, serialization

I'm trying to write a web service method that has a an object as one of it's parameters and that object has a property that is another object type.  There seems to be no problem with passing in a object as long as all of the objects properties are primitive types.  As soon as one of the properties is another object it has issues even if that embedded object is made of all primitives.

I'm using SoapUI to test it and the error I get is org.xml.sax.SAXException: No deserializer for {http://WebService}MyEmbeddedObject

I'm thinking there must be an easy way to tell it to deserialize the embedded object too but can't for the life of me figure out how.  At this point I'll take the hard way too I just need a solution, I can always try to improve it later.

The method in the web service I'm writing looks like this:

```
public boolean MethodName(MyObject object, String sessionID) throws Exception
{
    //do Stuff
}
```

The MyObject Class looks like this:

```
public class MyObject implements java.io.Serializable
{
    public String                           Description;
    public MyEmbeddedObject                 Thing1;
    public MyEmbeddedObject                 Thing2;
    public MyEmbeddedObject[]               Things;
}
```

The MyEmbeddedObject Class looks like this:

```
public class MyEmbeddedObject implements java.io.Serializable
{
    public String   SubThing1;
    public String   SubThing2;
    public String   SubThing3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this problem had nothing to do with implementing java.io.Serializable.  In fact you could remove that and it will work just fine as long as you fix the actual problem.

The actual problem being that you can't use an object as an argument unless all of it's properties are primitive types UNLESS you also use that embeded object in the method itself.  It seems to be some sort of compiler voodoo if you ask me but here's the solution in code.  Hopefully this makes sense.  I'll even take it one level deeper just for illustration purposes.

One thing you'll notice that I've changed in the solution is that the "MyEmbeddedObject" class is much more complicated looking.  This is because I didn't know how to properly define arrays in java at the time I asked this question.  I assumed it was the same as C# and unfortunately for me that compounded my problem but I eventually figured it out by banging my head long enough and reviewing sample code from the vendor this project is for.

Program

```
public boolean MethodName(MyObject object, String sessionID)
{
    //do Stuff
}
public MyEmbeddedObject unusedMyEmbeddedObject()
{
    return null;
}
public MyDoubleEmbeddedObject unusedMyDoubleEmbeddedObject()
{
    return null;
}
```

In a separate class file

```
public class MyObject
{
    public String                           description;
    public MyEmbeddedObject                 thing1;
    public MyEmbeddedObject                 thing2;
}
```

In a separate class file

```
public class MyEmbeddedObject
{
    public MyDoubleEmbeddedObject           subThing1;
    private MyDoubleEmbeddedObject[]        subThings;
    public MyDoubleEmbeddedObject[]         getSubThings()
    {
        return this.subThings;
    }
    public void setSubThings(final MyDoubleEmbeddedObject[] value)
    {
        this.subThings = value;
    }
}
```

In a separate class file

```
public class MyDoubleEmbeddedObject
{
    public String                           subSubString1;
    public String                           subSubString2;
    public String                           subSubString3;
}
```